# Can't generate random string

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
 for (int j = 0; j < fileBytes.size(); j++) {
        bitMap = convert.convertByteArray(fileBytes.get(j));
        db.addContact(new Case(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "1234",
                        bitMap[0], bitMap[1]));
 }
```

This codesnippet will make n objects of the `case` class based on how many files `fileBytes.size()` can list out.

As you can see I use the `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` just to generate a random `String`, this is the fist parameter in the `Case` constructor.

Each of these objects is saved to a `SQLite` database. This doesn't work, the random generated String doesn't show up. But if I replace the `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` with `Integer.toString(j)` this will show up. I cant really see why it shouldn't work..

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The problem was that the first parameter in the `case` class was a String, but the first field in the database was set to be an `INT`, change this field to a `VARCHAR`

Comment: what data type is the column that you are trying to put the UUID in to?

Comment: So i was correct according to the edit?

Answer (score 0):

Show up where? database? make sure the UUID is not too long or of the wrong datatype to get stored in the DB.

Comment: The String should show up in the ListView, it doesn't seems that the object is not created.

Comment: are you sure that it doesnt throw an exception somewhere along the way?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that. If thats the case, LogCat should shown me this error.

Comment: assume nothing. I suggest you run that code with a debugger and single-step through it if possible. I assume something in the Case constructor or DB is throwing an exception and the stuff is not getting created or stored.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
String randomStr = String.valueOf(Random.nextInt());
```

or

```
db.addContact(new Case(new String(UUID.randomUUID().toString()), "1234", bitMap[0], bitMap[1]));
```